# webserver running as nobody cannot resolve domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, php, centos6, nobody

If i try to run the following:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.yahoo.com/index.html"); ?>
```

through the web server I get a an "`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo`" error.

If I run the same file from the shell with:

```
php test.php
```

then I get the expected file output.

This indicates to me that the 'nobody' user, which the webserver runs as, is not able to resolve the domain name, but the shell user can.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Further info: CentOS 6, cPanel install, Apache, PHP running as dso.

BTW, I've tried disabling the firewall to no effect.

[SOLVED] - when I found that gethostbyname() was working, I realised that it was some internal caching problem. A server restart seems to have sorted out the problem.

Comment: what's the output of `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');` ?

Comment: @Sandman4 1 - that's the number one on it's own.

Comment: and if you do `echo gethostbyname('www.yahoo.com');` ?

Comment: then I get the IP number of yahoo.com (which i did not expect).

Comment: and if i do:
`echo file_get_contents("http://" . gethostbyname('www.yahoo.com') . "/index.html");`
then I get the webpage.
Hmm, I'm puzzled...

Comment: this is a creative one

Comment: what about `file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com');` ?

Comment: no change (I get the error).

Comment: Could it be that HTTP wrapper have some internal DNS cache, (which does not affect gethostbyname) ? can you restart apache ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3109/discussion-between-sandman4-and-jalal)

Comment: You should probably answer your own question, and then accept it, so you can close this question off.

Comment: Can someone close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From later comment by jalal: 
"[SOLVED] - when I found that gethostbyname() was working, I realised that it was some internal caching problem. A server restart seems to have sorted out the problem."

Repeating EightBitTony comment - please mark this question as answered.